# Python : Recursive Factorial

Tags: python, class, recursion, factorial

I am new to this coding world. Sorry, for such a noob question.
I was trying to run factorial function using classes. But getting following error : "TypeError: factorial() missing 1 required positional argument: 'input' ".

Can you guys please explain me the problem in here and how to solve the issue.

```
class cool:

def __init__(self, input):
    self.input = input



def factorial(self, input):
    self.input = input
    if self.input == 0 :
        return(1)
    else:
        return( factorial(self.input-1) * self.input)


var = cool(3)
print(var.factorial())
```

Comment: Change `self.input` to `input` everywhere, and pass `3` to the function instead of to the class constructor. And of course, you can subsequently make this function `@static` in the class (and get rid of `self` passed to it).

Comment: So, you can see why trying to put classes everywhere is not necessarily a good idea. Don't create a mess, keep it simple, use a function.

Comment: I don't really see what you need `self.input` for at all. You only need (and use) the `input` parameter of `factorial`, and for that you have to call it as `var.factorial(3)`

Answer (score 1):

I will echo what others have commented, it's odd to write `factorial` in a class like this, but hopefully it demonstrates how class methods can be recursive too.

Recursion is a functional heritage and so using it with functional style yields the best results. This means avoiding things like mutations, variable reassignments, and other side effects -

```py
class cool:
  def __init__(self, v):
    self.v = v

  def factorial(self):
    if self.v == 0:
      return 1
    else:
      return self.v * cool(self.v - 1).factorial()
```

```py
print(cool(3).factorial())
print(cool(4).factorial())
print(cool(5).factorial())
print(cool(6).factorial())
print(cool(7).factorial())
```

```py
6
24
120
720
5040
```

One adjustment you may consider is the handling of negative numbers -

```py
class cool:
  def __init__(self, v):
    self.v = v

  def factorial(self):
    if self.v == 0:
      return 1
    elif self.v < 0:
      return -1 * cool(self.v * -1).factorial()
    else:
      return self.v * cool(self.v - 1).factorial()
```

Now it works for positive and negative numbers -

```py
print(cool(7).factorial())
print(cool(-7).factorial())
```

```py
5040
-5040
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why are you using class for this.

here is the fix:

```
class cool:

    def __init__(self, input):
        self.input = input + 1  #<----

    def factorial(self): #<----
        if self.input == 1 : #<----
            return 1 
        else:
            self.input -= 1 #<----
            result = self.input * self.factorial()  #<----
            return result 


var = cool(3)
print(var.factorial())
```

---

`self.input * self.factorial()`  do this instead of `self.factorial() * self.input`

why???

because self.input will become 0 in the latter case. Because you're doing recursion and every time your input is getting decreases in the end. when recursion is done the returning value will get multiple by this self.input (which has become zero.)

Comment: I don't think you should use `self.input == 1` as the base case. `0!` is equal to the empty product, `1`.

Comment: Actually that will make the result to be 0. That's why used `self.input ==1 ` have to do modifications while using `self.input == 0`. Thanls for pointing this out. btw merry christmas in advance :)

Answer (score -1):

Use tabs, methods must be in class.
And maybe is better to use function factorial from module math?

Comment: While both is true, OP's error indicates that the code is actually properly indented and the problem lies somewhere else.